# Returning Array just gives Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple function where , I need to return all the values from the array regardless of how many there is currently inside - the issue is that it only returns "Array". I have already checked the array, with print_r and the array has content.

```
function RoomGroup($numberOfRooms){
    $adults = intval($_GET['adults']);
    $roomGroup = '';
    if ($numberOfRooms > 1){
        $roomGroupArray = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$numberOfRooms;$i++){
        $count = $i+1;
        $roomGroupArray[] = '&room' . $count . '=' . intval($_GET['adults']);
    }
    $roomGroup = array_values($roomGroupArray);
    print_r($roomGroup);
    }else if(empty($adults)){
            $roomGroup = '&room1=' . intval($_GET['guests']);
    }else{
            $roomGroup = '&room1=' . intval($_GET['adults']);
    }
    return $roomGroup;
}
```

It's within the IF sentence I create the array , and from here on return I get "Array". How can I just return the values within the array. It shouldn't be echo'et or printed to frontend , it is used within the php code.How do I do this?

Comment: Don't you need to give the index for `$roomGroup` (within the for loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you don't need $roomGroupArray at all. It looks like you can concatenate $roomGroup within the loop to build upon the existing string.

Is that what you're trying to do, and what you want to return?

Comment: that is what I'm trying to do yes. The roomGroupArray was to try an alternative way, I agree I don't need as I see it.

Comment: When I print_r I get Array ( [0] => &room1=2 [1] => &room2=2 [2] => &room3=2 ) When I echo it or return it through the function I just get "Array" - do you know why it is like that ? @Ro Mc

Comment: You're assigning each string to a new array element in the line:
$roomGroupArray[] = '&room' . $count . '=' . intval($_GET['adults']);

I think what you want to do is use
$roomGroup .= '&room' . $count. '=' . intval($_GET['adults']);

Give that a go

Comment: Yes I know , so what I wanted to do was to return all the values within the array - to put all the values together like: &room1=2&room2=2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

use `array_values($_GET['adults'])` to print out/append all the values.

Comment: I dont't see your point , as the issue lies within the IF sentence, where I don't use guests at all.

Comment: edited, sorry. You can use the array_values() function on any array to print out the values.